# Import environment settings into Makefile (ubuntu and osx)

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, makefile

In a shell script I can

```
. conf/environment
```

Can I do the same in Makefile?

Comment: The environment vaiables are automatically imported - are you aski to import settings as per title or import a file which has notthing to do with environment

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to import are a bunch of environment variable set in a shell script. I'm not sure what's the correct way to say this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no good solution, so here's the cleanest hack I can think of:

- have three layers of build scripts
- layer 1 is the Makefile
- layer 2 consists of a bunch of shell scripts, one per make target

In each shell script in layer 2, do

```
. conf/environment
```

then run the actual build script in layer 3

Answer (score 3):

Make has both `include` and `-include` (as well as `sinclude` that is kept for compatibility with other make tools) statements (later stands for “optional” inclusion). So you can do something like this:

```
PLATFORM := $(shell uname)
include conf/environment_$(PLATFORM).mk
```

Where every `environment_*.mk` defines the same variables but with different values depending on the platform they are targeting.

See [§3.3 “Including Other Makefiles”](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) of the GNU Make documentation for more details.

**UPDATE:**

If you are trying to actually import environment variables by running a shell script, there are two options. The first is to run your script before running make. Then you can access those variables inside Makefile. So you would do `source conf/environment && make`. Option number two is to modify your script and instead of doing `export`, do `echo` and then use Make's [`eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) command to execute that output as commands.

Comment: Just to be clear, this will only work if the file you're including is a makefile.  It won't work if the file is a shell script.  I.e., you can't include the same file as both a shell script via `.` and a makefile via `include`.  Actually, you CAN do that as long as the file you're including adheres to a very limited variable assignment syntax which is common between `make` and `sh`.

Comment: Well, in this case the conf/environment I'm trying to run is a shell script that does a bunch of EXPORT. Is there a way to make that work?

Comment: @Max: Not out of the box. You will have to hack around. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. One more attempt at this without hacking: is there a way to do something like beforeEach in Makefile? I guess if that's possible I can just run the env script in beforeEach.

Comment: @Max: What's `beforeEach`?

Comment: In the Makefile, there are make test, make compile, make clean, and a lot of other options. So rather than explicitly stating "conf/environment && node script_name --options=a" in each one (location of node is set in conf/environment), is there a way to globally specify running "conf/environment" before any task?

Comment: @Max: You'd have to run `. conf/environment` before running make and therefore it is not related to the make's target at all.